# hiding and displaying uitoolbar on same button click

Tags: iphone, uiview, hide

I am trying to hide and display a `UIView` on BarButtonItem click. Priviously i also posted the question regarding same but didnt find any suitable answer. I created UIView manually in IB and just placed it in view so it must be shown as soon as view is loaded but i made it hidden in viewDidLoad method by writing

```
myvew.hidden = YES;
```

secondly, when i click BarButtonItem then i set

```
-(IBAction)mymethod
{
     myview.hidden = NO; 
}
```

so its diplaying view but when i again click on it it must hide.. how do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (myview.hidden == YES)
{
myview.hidden = NO;
}
else
{
myview.hidden = YES;
}
```

Check if the view is already hidden and then show, and if not hidden then hide it.

Answer (score 3):

Put the following statement in your button action

```
   myview.hidden = !myview.hidden ;
```

So your code must be like below.

```
-(IBAction)mymethod
{
   myview.hidden = !myview.hidden ;
}
```

Comment: using the tag property doesnt work for me as u answered in my privious post!! it was just checking the if syntax and directly reaches to else part. instead, i used praveen's and VIToBrothers

Answer (score 0):

You should do in this way

```
-(IBAction)mymethod
{
    if( myview.hidden == NO ) myview.hidden = YES;
    else myview.hidden = NO; 
}
```